# Where can I find my 12 Recovery Passphrase

Tags: blockchain

Have just lost my blockchain wallet password have tried all kind of password I know now I need to know my recovery passphrase kindly help

Answer (score 3):

You can find it wherever you wrote it down when you first created the wallet... otherwise you're unfortunately SOL.

Comment: Is it a secret question..? Cause that is the only thing I remember I wrote down

Comment: Yeah, no. What wallet are you using?